# Gradient-Based Optimizations in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to solve a couple minimization problems using Python but the setup with constraints is difficult for me to understand. I have:

**minimize:** x+y+2z^2
**subject to:** x = 1 and x^2+y^2 = 1

This is very easy obviously and I know the solution is x=1,y=0,z=0. I tried to use `scipy.optimize.L-BFGS-B` but had issues.

I also have:
**minimize:** 2x1^2+x2^2
**subject to:** x1+x2=1

I need to use a gradient based optimizer so I chose `scipy.optimizer.COBYLA` but had issues using an equality constraint as it only takes inequality constraints. The code for this is:

```
def objective(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return 2*(x1**2)+ x2
def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]+x[1]-1
#Try an initial condition of x1=1 and x2=0
#Our initial condition satisfies the constraint already
x0 =  [0.3,0.7]
print(objective(x0))
xnew = [0.25,0.75]
print(objective(xnew))
#Since we have already calculated on paper we know that x1 and x2 fall between 0 and 1
#We can set our bounds for both variables as being between 0 and 1
b = (0,1)
bounds = (b,b)
#Lets make note of the type of constraint we have for out optimizer
con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun':constraint1}
cons = [con1]
sol_gradient = minimize(objective,x0,method='COBYLA',bounds=bounds, constraints=cons)
```

Then I get error about using equality constraints with this optimizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. Your objective function does not match with the description you have provided. Should it be this: `2*(x1**2) + x2**2`?
2. From the docs [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) you can see that COBYLA does not support `eq` as a constraint. From the page:

> Note that COBYLA only supports inequality constraints.

3. Since you said you want to use a Gradient based optimizer, one option could  be to use the [Sequential Least Squares Programming (SLSQP)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp) optimizer.

Below is the code replacing `'COBYLA'` with `'SLSQP'` and changing the objective function according to 1:

```
def objective(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return 2*(x1**2)+ x2**2
def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]+x[1]-1
#Try an initial condition of x1=1 and x2=0
#Our initial condition satisfies the constraint already
x0 =  [0.3,0.7]
print(objective(x0))
xnew = [0.25,0.75]
print(objective(xnew))

#Since we have already calculated on paper we know that x1 and x2 fall between 0 and 1
#We can set our bounds for both variables as being between 0 and 1
b = (0,1)
bounds = (b,b)
#Lets make note of the type of constraint we have for out optimizer
con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun':constraint1}
cons = [con1]
sol_gradient = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bounds, constraints=cons)
print(sol_gradient)
```

Which gives the final answer as:

```
    fun: 0.6666666666666665
     jac: array([1.33333336, 1.33333335])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 7
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.33333333, 0.66666667])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. I didn't know about the ```SLSQP``` package. The worked perfectly, thank you so much :)